# How to slice the data of tf.data.Dataset type to certain length in TF2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am following this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/text#split_the_dataset_into_text_and_train_batches), in this I want to trim the length of each sentence stored in (sentence, label) tuple of `tf.data.Dataset` type to length 8 or n. I tried using tf.map function with lambda but can not do it since lambda only accepts one argument and it is receiving **sentences** and **label** arguments. `train_data = train_data.map(lambda x : x[:4])`

I will be thankful if anyone can give their ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet to do the required operation.

```
import tensorflow as tf
vocab_size = 10000

sentences = tf.random.uniform(shape=[10000, 15], minval=0, maxval=vocab_size, dtype=tf.int32)
labels = tf.random.uniform(shape=[10000, 1], minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

assert sentences.shape == tf.TensorShape([10000, 15])
assert labels.shape == tf.TensorShape([10000, 1])


def trim_sentences(sentence, label, n=8):
    return sentence[:n], label

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sentences, labels)) 
#<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((15,), (1,)), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>

dataset = dataset.map(trim_sentences) 
#<MapDataset shapes: ((8,), (1,)), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. I also found an easier way by just adding `padded_text = encoded_text[:n]` (n= the padding length) inside `map` function. However, now I want to implement this for TPUs and on TPUs, `py_func` is not supported. Any ideas on how I can replace it with some tf ops or `tf.data` functions?

Comment: yeah thats, kind of the same thing what i wrote above. As far as TPU's are concerned the above dataset would work just fine!

Comment: After reading some docs, I found out `from_tensor_slices`, as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) for small dataset like this it will be fine but not for bigger datasets as it will consume more memory. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sentences, labels)) ` i did this for the sake of simplicity. The right way to do this would be convert your data into tfrecords, upload them to GCS bucket and then write a fast enough data input pipeline to keep the TPU busy at all time. More information on this here 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

Comment: your provided link looks like the correct way. However, I still can not understand, on how to perform tokenizing, encoding and padding using the map function. [This is](https://gist.github.com/rishabhsahrawat/9a6ba748e31bb2f14f05bd861a5b9ca5) how I imagine it should work but I just can not make it work. I can also provide full code.